# How to properly add a page template in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm trying to add 2 page templates (one would be my default page, and one extra) using wordpress as a a CMS (content management system).

I have 2 php files, one named VM.php (my default page) and the other lol.php (I'm just testing here, so excuse my funny page names). On BOTH files, at the very top I have written the script to their corresponding pages:

```
<?php /* Template Name: VM */ ?>

<?php /* Template Name: lol */ ?>
```

As you can see in the screen shot below, I have both files in the the parent folder of wp-content/themes as well as in a sub folder wp-content/themes/my-theme (I tried using the sub folder alone with nothing in the parent folder to see if it would work, and also tried it by deleting the sub folder, either way it didn't work).

Here is the link to the old screen shot:

```
http://s1228.photobucket.com/user/Ebadly/media/random/ScreenShot2013-11-20at12342PM_zps4b0c04d6.png.html
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the option of choosing page templates when creating a new template is not showing up. Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
Here is a new screen shot to show the new hierarchy of the my-theme folder:

[image: Here is a new screen shot to show the new hierarchy of the my-theme folder:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. In order to create page templates you must have at least 2 pages and  also the index.php and style.css (the only necessary php comment needed in the style.css is Theme Name: your-theme-name).

After doing so, you MUST put these 4 files into a zipped folder, then head to Appearance --> Themes, click the tab "install" theme. Upload the zipped folder. Then you can "activate" your theme. This final step of installing the theme will allow the "page templates" option to show.

I hate answering my own question, but this was the final step I needed: installing the theme via zip folder. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Make sure you mark your answer Accepted once you're able to do so, so that other can benefit from your experience. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot indicates a structure like this:

```
themes
...
    my-theme
        lol.php
        VM.php
```

Reading the [Codex page on Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), I find that

> At the very minimum, a WordPress Theme consists of two files:
>
> `style.css`
>
> `index.php`

Have a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) as well.  Note that your theme should *always* have at least an `index.php` file as a default template file (unless you're writing a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)).

**Edit**

At a minimum, the `style.css` file should contain the name of your theme:

```
/*
Theme Name: [whatever you want to call your theme]
*/
```

If you haven't yet, read through the [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) page on the Codex (especially the [Basic Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates) section).

Comment: I added a style.css and index.php into my-theme folder including the other 2 php files. I'm still not getting the option to choose a page template.

Comment: Did you activate the theme once you had the `style.css` and `index.php` files in place?

Comment: How do I do that? I went to the "themes" section in the wp-admin page on the left, yet I don't see my theme in order to activate it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you haven't yet, you really should read about Themes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

The default page template is `page.php` (if not present, `index.php` will be used) which should be in your theme's root folder and to create a custom page template you should name it like

```
page-{slug}.php
// or
page-{ID}.php
```

and put this inside your theme's root folder too. For example, if you want to create a custom page template as `lol` then it should be save using name `page-lol.php` and in this template file put this at first, this will be visible in the `template` combo box (`Lol Page`)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Lol Page
*/
```

My `twentythirteen` theme folder

```
wp-content
    themes
        twentythirteen
        // other files
        page.php
        page-lol.php
        style.css
        // other filse
```

**Screenshot :** ([Read more on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates))

[image]

**Update :** I'm not sure if you are doing it right, if you don't have a `style.css` file then `WordPress` won't recognize your theme and in your `style.css` file you have to put some information (stylesheet header) as well (WP need these information),  here is an example ([Read more on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development))

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Thirteen
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2013 theme for WordPress takes us back to the blog, featuring a full range of post formats, each displayed beautifully in their own unique way. Design details abound, starting with a vibrant color scheme and matching header images, beautiful typography and icons, and a flexible layout that looks great on any device, big or small.
Version: 1.1
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-width, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
Text Domain: twentythirteen

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

Also, make sure you have activated your theme from admin panel `Appearance -> Themes` menu.

Comment: I change VM.php to page.php and lol.php to page-lol.php ... still the template under page attributes still not showing up.

Comment: Did you add the comment `Template Name: Lol Page` at first and are those files in your theme's root folder ?

Comment: @EbadSaghar If the `VM.php` and `lol.php` files aren't in a valid theme (ie, one with `style.css` and `index.php`), they won't show up in the Template dropdown box.

Comment: I just added style.css and index.php into "my-theme" folder. Still the option is not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing `style.css` and `index.php` in your theme - both files are required.

Add these within `my-theme` and make sure to put the required comments at the top of `style.css`

```
/*
Theme Name: my-theme
Theme URI: http://localhost/wordpress/my-theme
Author: Me
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
etc ...
*/
```

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet):

> The comment header lines in **style.css** are required for WordPress to be able to identify the Theme and display it in the Administration Panel under Design > Themes as an available Theme option along with any other installed Themes.

Comment: What does style.css consist of? Can I have it just blank?

Comment: Also, what about the index.php? I have that blank as well.

Comment: @EbadSaghar: As long as you have both `index.php` and `style.css` within the `my_theme` directory and have activated your theme from `Appearance -> Themes` it should work. Note that you won't have an image associated with your theme, like the default do, it will instead just list the name of your theme.

Comment: That's the issue. I don't see the name of my theme in Appearance -> Theme. It's not there.

Comment: Are you running WordPress Multisite? If so, then you (or a network super admin, if you're not one) needs to Network Enable your theme.